# Using a header file instead of the standard namespace

Tags: c++, header, std

I am curious if there is any header file in C++ which can be used (included) instead of the standard namespace (`namespace std`) that works the same even in new versions of C++? I want to know if I can write code without using any namespaces and still be able to use the string data type.

Comment: Why don't you want to add namespaces?

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std` and no, because it's a terrible idea

Comment: I'm guessing, because there is a bunch of old code that doesn't have namespace qualifiers.

Comment: I want it to be compatible with old C++ code but I can't use <iostream.h> because my compiler is not old.

Comment: FWIW, <iostream.h> is more than fifteen years old.

Comment: The only way to fix old code is to fix it.

Comment: How big is your code base? It's probably best to bite the bullet.

Comment: Please, show the example of code, that compiles with old C++ compiler  (BTW, what is that "old" compiler name and version) and do not compiles with nowadays one

Comment: I've heard that there is some old header file that defines the string data type and doesn't need the standard namespace to function, and works in new versions of C++. I guess this is false then?

Comment: @MohammadSanei If you mean header string.h then you're wrong, because it do **not** define `string` type. This header contains functions declarations to work with null-terminating strings, that represent as a pointer to charachter sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is in the `std` namespace, so you can't completely disregard it.

There are options though:

```
using std::string;
using namespace std;
typedef std::string myString;

//or fully qualify the name
std::string mystr;
```

which you can put in a header and include that.

There, now I gave you the recipe for disaster. **Don't use it!**

**Namespaces are good.** Learn to use them, rather than hacking your way around them.

Comment: `using std::string;` at least makes it clear that "I need one specific part a lot", rather than "*lololo*, bring teh codez on". (Still, *don't* put it in headers)

Comment: What is the difference between "std::string MyString" and "typedef std::string MyString" in functionality?

Comment: @MohammadSanei the first creates a variable, the second defines a type.

Comment: So then I'll be able to use MyString as a shorthand for std::string?

Answer (score 2):

Headers and namespaces are not related, and namespaces are good things. `using namespace std` is bad. You can always use the `std::string` data type without `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 2):

To use "using namespace std;" is a poor idea (although I have to admit I do this rather regularly in my samples I post here, for ease of typing). To hide the same in a header file is an even worse idea.

Namespaces are there for a reason.

But if you have, say, 100000 lines of already existing code that is written pre-namespace standard, and you quickly want to port that to use in a new compiler, then adding "using namespace std;" to the top of each file would be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could `typedef` the classes you wish to use, but this is a really bad idea.

```
#include <string>
typedef std::string string;
```

Comment: `using std::string;` is the preferred way of bringing string into the current namespace.

Comment: Yes, I know. But they didn't want to use `using`, and it's not good to pollute a header with `using`, either. Although, saying that, I'm just polluting with a different typename instead.

Comment: That's perfect! I just got what you were saying! Is there any way to define cout and endl in a similar way inside a header file without polluting it with `using`?

Comment: It's a perfectly terrible idea.

Comment: Is there any way to define cout in a similar way?